# Using values within multiple <option>'s inside two dropdown selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

having issue with my TWO dropdowns, not displaying the specific values based on the selection of the first box. Currently all values display regardless of which first option is selected.

I am currently using Jquery 1.6 with the actual code. See Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaisonbrooks/QFyGX/)

Here is a example of my HTML.

```
<select name="column_select" id="column_select">
<option id="1" value="/search_option_1">First</option>
<option id="2" value="/search_option_2">Second</option>
<option id="3" value="/search_option_3">Third</option>
</select>

<select name="layout_select" id="layout_select">

<!-- Child options from Parent Option 1 -->
<option id="1" value="/first_value/one">1.1</option>
<option id="1" value="/first_value/two">1.2</option>

<!-- Child options from Parent Option 2 -->
<option id="2" value="/second_value/one">2.1</option>
<option id="2" value="/second_value/two">2.2</option>

<!-- Child options from Parent Option 3 -->
<option id="3" value="/third_value/one">3.1</option>
<option id="3" value="/third_value/two">3.2</option>
</select>
```

Now as you can see im using the `id=""` to be able to reference which options go with which first selection box. Im doing this because i need to specify specific values for each option. See the demo code for more insight and what im trying to accomplish.

Thanks

Comment: ID's **must** be unique, or else the HTML won't be valid, FYI :D

Comment: @tymeJV Yeah i know this, im just unsure how to link these options with the right parent option. and still have different values for each option.

Comment: You can always use an instance of `this`, however both of your selects have ID's, so I believe @Ringo's answer will work just fine.

Comment: I realize now what you might be trying to do is show different options in the second select box depending on which option is selected in the first select box. Is this true?

Comment: @Ringo You are exactly correct

Comment: So it's not really solved then. Your options are to have three different select fields, and you hide the two that arent being used. That's not a bad way to do it. Or else, you have to dynamically populate one select field. If you want help with that, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#multi_select').click(function() {
      var url = 'http://www.urlimusing.com/' + $('#column_select').val() + $('#layout_select').val();
      window.location = url;
    });
});
```

Everything else in your existing document ready looks weird and bad. Just throw those lines away.